# Extraction of Names from Resumes and then changing the name present in the resume

Tags: python, text, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am currently interning at a company and the project that I am working on involves the extraction of names from Resumes, changing or tweaking the name and then getting the resume back in the original format.

I have been following [this](https://dataturks.com/blog/named-entity-recognition-in-resumes.php) blog from Dataturks, it involves extracting entities from resumes. I just wanted to know if there is an even better way of doing this and has this work(changing and tweaking names) been done before?

Comment: By changing name you mean encrypting them for security or something else??

Comment: First the name has to be detected or extracted from the resume. Then will look at the next steps.

Comment: I'd imagine it's a recruitment agency that wants to obfuscate the name of their clients.

Comment: NER systems as mentioned in the blog are not very good at person names. You could start by scraping a lot of names from the internet, tag them in your data then train your own NER or finetune a pretrained one( use spacy etc.).

If you want deterministic approach then just use your scraped names to search from your resumes and use regex as validation.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how to deal with mutli page resumes?